# Java generics: get class of generic method's return type

Tags: java, generics, jsp-tags

### Background

I once wrote this method:

```
private <T> SortedSet<T> createSortedSet() {
  return new TreeSet<T>();
}
```

It's supposed to be called like this:

```
Set<String> set = createSortedSet();
```

This works fine (although I've seen in answers here when researching the current question that this is error-prone).

### The current situation

Anyway, now I am writing the following code (in a class that extends javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport):

```
private <T> T evaluate(String expression) {
  ExpressionEvaluator evaluator = pageContext.getExpressionEvaluator();
  return evaluator.evaluate(expression, T, null, pageContext.getVariableResolver());
}
```

The purpose is to be able to call this like:

```
Integer width = evaluate(widthStr);
```

The code in my evaluate method obviously doesn't work. The second argument to `evaluator.evaluate()` is supposed to be a Class object. This leads me to:

### My question

How can I get the Class of a generic (return) type? What should I write in place of T as the second argument to evaluate?

### EDIT: Conclusion

Nicolas seems to be right, it can not be done and I need to pass the class as an argument to my method. The upside is that since his solution makes the argument parametrized on the generic type I get a compilation check on that argument.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will certainly have to change your method to:

```
private <T> T evaluate(Class<T> clazz, String expression)
```

and then pass `clazz` as your second parameter. Not as short as you expected.

Comment: Thanks! After experimenting with various reflection based ideas, I can not disagree with you.

Comment: Basically the problem exists because of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 3):

> [image: #ff0000] **This doesn't work with all JVM!**

You can first create a generic object and then retrieve its parameterized type:

```
private <T> T evaluate(String expression) {
  List<T> dummy = new ArrayList<>(0);
  Type[] actualTypeArguments = ((ParameterizedType) dummy.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();
  Type clazz = actualTypeArguments[0];
  Class<T> theClass = (Class<T>) clazz.getClass();

  ExpressionEvaluator evaluator = pageContext.getExpressionEvaluator();
  return evaluator.evaluate(expression, theClass, null, pageContext.getVariableResolver());
}
```

Beware! You don't get a `Class<>` object, you get a `TypeVariableImpl` subclass object, which may behave differently.